# Not all CSS properties applied to <hr> tag in blazor, Background color creates different color than value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor

I tried to color my hr tag in Blazor but it did not work. The part that I am very surprised with is that the hr color is reflected differently. For example, the black color was always gray and the red color orange. I have tried all the approaches. By the way, the high property worked well but the color never did. Any ideas?

```
insline:
<hr style="height:20px; background-color: black;">

CSS isolation
hr{
   height:20px; '
   background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap sets the opacity. `background-color: black;` is working...

Try:

```
<hr style="height: 20px; background-color: green; opacity: 100%;" />
```

As a style:

```
hr {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

If your not using isolation you may need `!important` on `height`.